# how to implement social networks dynamically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how can I add/remove dynamically social networks in wordpress.
the html code below, is inside header.php.

```
<ul class="social-share">
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li> 
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

what have I to put in functions.php in order to add/remove them dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

Using this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-social-icons/

You will get add/edit/delete option for icons

(or)

using CSS style you can hide the unwanted icons.